# KS, AD and loglike results

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, likelihood, anderson-darling-test

I'm using R to test some distribution families to my data.
I've done KS, AD tests and determined the loglike.

For one of the data the indications given by KS and AD do not agree with the ones given by the loglike:

```
Table: p-values
Test    Normal  Log-normal  Gamma   Logistic    Weibull Gumbel
KS      0,16    0,00        0,00    0,26        0,00    0,49
AD      0,17    0,00        0,00    0,27        0,00    -

Measure Normal  Log-normal  Gamma   Logistic    Weibull Gumbel
loglike 282,86  279,54      308,96  284,41      304,00  291,55
```

I've read that KS gives more emphasis to the middle part of the distributions and AD to the tails. On the loglike one maximizes the probability of a model fitting the data.
The graphical analysis says to me that Log-normal, Gamma and Weibull only fit the data well at the left tail whereas the other distributions fit data quite well all over the domain....
So why does these three dist. have a larger loglike than the others that seem to fit better the data? Thanks

Comment: What is the meaning of the values in the first table? The test statistic? The p-value? Something else? Are you using one-sided or two-sided KS test?

Comment: p-value. Edited question text

Comment: A p-value $0,00$ is very intriguing. It means that the test statistic is huge. Note also that you are comparing distributions with different support and different skewness. What is the motivation for comparing such different models? Are you fixing the parameters *a priori*? The fit of the log-normal and the Gamma should not be extremely different. If you are fixing the parameters, this may be the reason for such extreme differences.

Comment: It's not quite zero, it has been rounded. The data is truncated at zero so I thought of trying only positive distributions and others that are defined -Inf, +Inf. I've also tested truncated distributions and in the end I'll comment on the results. But my question is really about the loglike results :)

Comment: Note that you are comparing two kinds of tests: a parametric test and a nonparametric test. What values are you using for the parameters and how did you choose them?

Comment: Note that the log-likelihood is an assessment of goodness of fit, & that *lower* values indicate a better fit. The low p-values mean you are rejecting the idea that your data came from a log-normal, gamma, or Weibull, & the higher LL for gamma & Weibull is consistent w/ that. Only the lower LL for the log-normal seems to be inconsistent.

Comment: @gung the function output is loglike and not -loglike, so larger values are better. Right?

Comment: @Procrastinator I've determined the distribution parameters using MLE.

Comment: Good question, what is the function being used here?

Comment: I'm using `fitdist` of `fitdistrplus` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding comparing the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and Anderson-Darling, the KS test is based on comparing the hypothesized distribution to the empirical distribution function.  It has general applicability and hence is not as powerful when testing against normality as tests designed for the normal such as Anderson-Darling and Shapiro-Wilk.

Regarding the loglikelihood function, its value depends on where the data lie.  To your eye you may see one distribution fitting better in the tail but if there are very few points in the tail the tail might not get much weight in the likelihood function.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm close to understand why! I've a bunch of results very close to 0 (say 1e-5), that total 15% of my data. The rest is more or less dispersed. Thus there are a lot of terms at the left tail and since the LN, Weibull and Gamma fit this part better they have a larger likelihood. Right?

Comment: That is probably the reason.